# jQuery countdown date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, countdown

I have this piece of JavaScript code I got from online and I am trying to modify itto countdown to July 10, 2013.

```
var currentDate = new Date();
$('div#clock').countdown(45 * 40 * 30 * 30 * 1000 + currentDate.valueOf(), function(event) {
```

[image]

July 10, 2013 is about 100 days from now so I want the days to show 100. I don't understand the format of how the date is being passed,I have tried messing around with it but it still doesn't work properly. I tried passing a new  Date object to it but that doesn't work either. This code seems to be coming from this [jQuery countdown library](https://github.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "45 * 40 * 30 * 30 * 1000" use "100 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000" so:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
$('div#clock').countdown(45 * 40 * 30 * 30 * 1000 + currentDate.valueOf(), function(event) {
```

would be the final code. That is 1000 (milliseconds/second) * 60 (seconds/minute) * 60 (minutes/hour) * 24 (hours/day) * 100 (days).